# Как сделать выплывающие элементы в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, анимация

Мне нужно сделать две выплывающие снизу кнопки, которые появляются при прокрутке.
Покажу на примере приложения Алиэкспресс. При прокрутке у нас плавно выезжают кнопки "Фильтр" и "Характеристики":

[image: При прокрутке у нас плавно выезжают кнопки "Фильтр" и "Характеристики"]

А при прокрутке вверх эти самые кнопки исчезают:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я использовал `LinearLayout` вместе с `ScrollView`, я просто подключал обработчик `OnScrollChangeListener` и в зависимости от направления прокрутки запускал нужную анимацию для кнопок, когда же я подключаю этот обработчик к `RecyclerView`, то обработчик реагирует на скролл, но `oldScrollY` и `scrollY` равны 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этих целей необходимо использовать `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`. В его методе `onScroll` есть параметр `dy`, отвечающий за прокрутку по оси y. В этом параметре передаётся количество пикселей, прокрученных за 1 движение. Значение может быть как положительным (прокрутка вниз), так и отрицательным (прокрутка вверх). Пример использования можно найти [здесь](https://gist.github.com/zTrap/530f97a8326374824e8ca3c714c847b8)

Что касается самой панели - есть несколько вариантов реализации:

- `RelativeLayout` как родительский `ViewGroup` для этой панели + `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` в свойствах `xml` у панели
- `FrameLayout` как родительский `ViewGroup` для этой панели + `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` в свойствах `xml` у панели

Для анимации можно использовать великолепную библиотеку [SlideUp](https://github.com/mancj/SlideUp-Android), которая имеет "под капотом" много плюшек для создания собственного слайдера.

Так же есть ещё 1 вариант реализации панели:

- `CoordinatorView` как родительский `ViewGroup` для этой панели + `BottomSheetBehavior`

[Google - документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html) и [пример использования](https://habrahabr.ru/post/309200/)